# Picture uploading using curl/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, firebug

I am trying to upload image using php/curl on a website using curl/php. The website uses ajax/flash to upload images to external server. When I upload an image manually on the website, using firebug, I just receive the response (with permanent link) if the image is successfully uploaded but I don't see what parameters and data were posted and where exactly.

web url where image needs to be uploaded:

http://tinyurl.com/bp779wx

How do I find out what parameters need to be sent in order to get the image uploaded successfully on the website?

Comment: you want to sent directly to the external server? there's no way you can observe what the webserver is doing to talk to the external server.

Comment: Not directly... I will log in and stuff using curl and use the same cookies to appear as a real user. There is some ajax stuff there though that gives you some parameters. There is also some token available. I think if I find out the name of the parameters I will be good.

Comment: @zista what do you mean with "but I don't see what parameters and data were posted"?

Comment: That link redirects to 'Gumtree : Post an ad', are you sure it is an image uploader site?

Comment: @JavierBrooklyn yes, see "select images" there.

Comment: @NannuoLei in order to upload images using curl there is some data needs to be posted such as token number etc.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the CURL code that you are using.

Comment: how would that help? the curl code i am using got nothing to do with image uploading functionality.

Comment: A view source of the target pages reveals that the name of the parameter for the images is `u`:

    <input type="file" name="u" size="40" style="width:500px" />

Comment: if you can use firebug to mess with your server then you are probably at risk of being hack with some nice XSS attack.

Answer (score 3):

The specific uploader you have mentioned extracts the epsToken variable from the following URL, then uses it as a parameter to upload the file.

http://johannesburg.gumtree.co.za/c-GetEpsToken

In my case, the token was:

> 1:b6ac30fa715a395cf728ac29847b2516f701a8f291fd5243d5153eae41c10636

You can see the full POST data for the upload request I made [here](http://pastebin.com/s9ZNJwAf). Keep in mind that this is a multipart/form-data request so you may need to adjust your curl/PHP code to support that.

Basically, the following parameters were supplied via the POST request:

```
Filename = Image.png 
b = 18 
s = 1C5000 
n = k 
a = 1:b6ac30fa715a395cf728ac29847b2516f701a8f291fd5243d5153eae41c10636
v = k 
r = 0 
u = the actual image, sent as a multipart stream 
Upload = Submit Query
```

I suggest you analyse the other parameters and use the code from the other answers in order to successfully upload the image.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer to me. @zista will need to get the key from first url, then send the image according to your post data. I tried to upload some images too and all of the data were same except the token. (I am still wondering how did you find out the token url)

Comment: The data extraction (including the url and all other variables) was done with a HTTP intercepting proxy. In this case, I used [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). It is a wonderful tool that speeds up web application development by logging all requests done to the server. You can even modify/intercept requests and send them back.

Comment: Just curious, but wouldn't you be able to extract the same information via the network tab in the Google Chrome developer tools? For intercepting and modifying requests, you'd need something like Charles though.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that information is also available in the Chrome developer tools _Network_ tab. However, the data is not as well structured in the developer tools as it is in Charles. This is a matter of _personal preference_, you can do the same thing with Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 2):

Upload image with PHP and cURL.

```
function curl_post_request($url, $data, $referer='') {
$data = http_build_query($data); // seems to be required arrays should'nt be supported  ? whatever.
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$output = curl_exec($c);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));
//var_dump($data);
if($output === false) trigger_error('Erreur curl : '.curl_error($c),E_USER_WARNING);
curl_close($c);
return $output;
}

if(isset($_GET['GO'])) {

$data = array(
'pic1' => "@".realpath('image.jpg'),
'postedvar1' => 'test1',
'postedvar2' => 'test2'
 );
$url = 'http://localhost/test/index.php';
$a = curl_post_request($url, $data);
var_dump($a);

} else {

print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Upload image using CURL + PHP via remote form

```
 $info = array('test title','1234','virginia','@'.realpath('e:\wamp  
 \www\1.jpg'),'@'.realpath('e:\wamp\www\2.jpg'),'@'.realpath('e:\wamp\www
 \3.jpg'),'@'.realpath('e:\wamp\www\4.jpg'),'test description');
  $post->postAd($url, $info);
```

Also Please read this

http://www.maheshchari.com/upload-image-file-to-remote-server-with-php-curl/

And see this link

http://blog.smileylover.com/remote-upload-to-imageshackus-with-phpcurl/

And

http://blogs.digitss.com/php/curl-php/posting-or-uploading-files-using-curl-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

Some problem with the site's image uploaded - it just pops up an error

> There was an error uploading your picture. Please check the image size
>   and dimension and try again. If you continue to have issues, you can
>   switch to the basic image loader.

for every type of images and basic image loader is also not actually available!.